# JPA Inheritance design issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create JPA entities using inheritance for the below data model. I have a price table with id, start and end date. There are different pricing types like standard price where user is charged per hour and volume price where he is charged based on volumes sold. In case of Tier price there is multiple entries for same price entry. For example if volume is 0 to 100 its going 1$, 101 to 1000 price would 1.25$ and more than 1000 it would 1.50$. Below is my data model

```
Price
ID
Start_Date
End_Date

Standard Price
ID
price_id(FK)
price

Tier Price
ID
Price_id (FK)
start_tier
end_tier
```

I am trying to persist price details using Spring Boot & JPA and model the entities. I am planning to use inheritance strategy, having price base class and Standard and Tier Price as subclass. I am facing problem with Tier Price subclass as multiple rows together form one single price entry. Below is what i am visualizing in model but this does not may to Enity. Is there a way to create an Entity to meet the below requirements or only way is to change data model by introducing new table to group tier information.

```
public class TierPriceHolder extends price{

private List<Tiers> price;

}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. What does `price_id` in `Standard Price` and `Tier Price` point to?

Comment: Price -> 1 | 1-Jan 2020 | 31 Dec 2020  and Standard Price -> 100 | 1 (FK)| 20$. In this example Standard price of 20$ is valid between 1st Jan 2020 and 31st Dec 2020. As there can many pricing types, had moved the start and end to parent table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to comment on whether nesting structured information in a flat table like that is a sound idea, but if you want to keep it all in a single table, you'll simply need an additional parent entity grouping the tiered prices:

```
public class VolumePrice extends Price {

   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name = "volume_price_id")
   private Collection<TierPrice> tiers;
}
```

With such a hierarchy, you'll simply get a parent row with multiple child rows pointing to it, all within the same table:

```
+----+----------+-----------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------------+
| id | price_id | volume_price_id | start_date | end_date    | start_tier | end_tier | DTYPE       |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 1  |          |                 | 1 Jan 2020 | 31 Dec 2020 |            |          | Price       |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 2  | 1        |                 |            |             |            |          | VolumePrice |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 3  |          | 2               |            |             | 0          | 100      | Tier        |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------------+
|    |          | 2               |            |             | 101        | 200      | Tier        |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------------+
```

(I am still confused about the meaning of `price_id`, but I hope you get the general idea)